# C++ pass STL container items as reference

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference

I have a map of type `std::map<std::string, std::vector<MyClass>>`. The map is filled in this way that I create a vector and put it with a guid as a pair  into the map. Then I want to call a function, give the just inserted vector to it and let it fill the vector. It looks like that:

```
{
    std::string guid = "aGUID"
    std::vector<MyClass> vec_myClass(0);
    my_map[guid] = vec_myClass;
    std::vector<MyClass>& vec_ref = my_map[guid];

    FillVector(vec_ref);    
}

FillVector(std::vector<MyClass>& vec)  { vec.push_back(...); }
```

I think the [] operator returns a reference of the item in `my_map`, which I can give to a function to work with it, but my application crashes at this point. I am putting the vector first into the map (when it is empty) because I want to avoid copying effort as function FillVector puts lots of items into the vector. Where is my mistake? Might it be wrong to pass a reference by reference to a function? Or is there a clearly better solution to this? I prefer references over pointers here. Thx, and all the best.

Comment: A small testcase that people can try to compile and run themselves would be ideal, as the problem might be in the code parts we can not see.

Comment: The surrounding code is quite huge, would be hard to extract a testcase. Are there online possibilites to supply test cases in c++ (like jsFiddle)?

Comment: You mean likie ideone.com and liveworkspace.org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that code simplifies to:

```
{
    std::string guid = "aGUID"
    FillVector(my_map[guid]);    
}
```

Btw. I think your problem does not appear to be here, but in code you don't show us...

Comment: That simplification is nice. I think you are right, the error is somewhere else. First I had everything working with pointer instead of references: std::map<std::string, std::vector<MyClass>*> . That worked fine ...

Comment: In my application I actually store the reference to the vec in a class which supplies the FillVector method. Maybe I get problems because the reference gets killed when the class is destroyed?

Comment: That is controlled by the life time of the map, the reference is to the vector that is the value in the map, so as long as the map is alive, the reference will be valid.

Comment: Yes ok. I am restructuring my algorithm. I only did the effort to avoid copyiing "big" vector objects. The objects of MyClass stored in the vector carry lots of data and I want to avoid that this data is copied when I simply insert a (full) vector into the map. But does the vector copy constructor actually make a deep copy?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, if you do as I highlighted in the code above and the function accepts a reference, there is no copying involved. If the function accepts by value, then there will be a copy (which will invoke the copy constructor for all the items in the vector.)

Comment: Your simplified code works well, yes. Ok I see std::vector does a deep copy. I chose the approach of give the vector object to be filled to the FillVector function rather than make it fill a vector, fetch the result and put it into my map, where a copy would be necessary.

Comment: I found the error in my code in iterating through my_map: std::vector<MyClass> vec_myClass = it->second; This invokes a copy constructor for the vector, and the copy is destroyed after iteration. But MyClass has a destructor which deletes OpenGL ressources which other instances of MyClass rely on. So I had to do it like this: std::vector<MyClass>& vec_MyClass = it->second;

Answer (score 0):

std::map operator would create value for the key internally if it does not exist. see [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5b%5d/). passing the reference to function is ok, the problem seem to be somewhere else in your code.